# Insert image into wordpress dynamic field with loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am a junior developer trying to solve a situation, in which I am uncertain how to proceed. I am thinking of a foreach loop to make an image printed out on the Wordpress field, but I can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction how I should do it?

So far I ve got this, but It does not yield any results.

Note: The forbidden image on the list to the right (cons) is hardcoded and I cannot seem to get them on each field.

[image: Pros and Cons Table]
[image]

Comment: Could you post yoг code example, that we can check and help you find problem

Comment: Sorry, my bad - was fiddling around with code. I have uploaded my code via screenshot.

Comment: You can insert your code in your question.  Screenshots will likely get downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to replace the starting `+` symbol of every line you can replace your loop with something like:

```php
foreach($new_pros as $key => $row_text) {
    $new_pros[$key] = preg_replace('/^\+/', '<img src="../assets/img/advantages-forbidden.svg">', $row_text);
}
```

A few other notes:

**1.** Using `../assets/` is generally bad practice in WordPress theme development. Instead use the `get_template_directory()` funcion, e.g.

```php
echo '<img src="'. get_template_directory() .'/assets/img/advantages-forbidden.svg">';
```

**2.** I would concider using an [ACF Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) field instead of a text field for both `pros_block` and `cons_block`. For example, set up a repeater for each pro/con block like:

[image]

Your code implementation would then be something like:

```php
if ( have_rows( 'pros_block' ) ) {
    while( have_rows( 'pros_block' ) ) {
        the_row();
        $show_icon = get_sub_field( 'show_icon' );
        $row_text = get_sub_field( 'text' );

        if ( $show_icon ) {
            echo '<img src="'. get_template_directory() .'/assets/img/advantages-forbidden.svg">';
        }

        echo $row_text;
    }
}
```

Hope this puts you on the right track.